# Android 3.0 Action bar on rotation

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

For 3.0 action bar, can I define two action bar styles for portrait and landscape? 
The action bar does not reset itself(such as hide the icons when there is no space available) when I switch from landscape to portrait mode.
I am using sdk 11 with compatibility library.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. On rotation, Activity is recreated. So in create method, you can set view and ActionBar properties based on current orientation.

Comment: Yes, I read that too. But the activity nor the fragment are being recreated. I have defined different layouts for landscape and portrait, but when I rotate the device the layout does not change and I have a breakpoint in onCreate that never gets hit. Is there something I am missing....